# Why does my child class not inherit properties from the parent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I am trying to understand Javascript's prototypical inheritance model but there seems to be something I am missing.  I have created the following set of objects:

```js
function Dog() {
  this.legs = 4;
  this.arms = 0;
}

Dog.prototype.describe = function() {
  console.log("Has " + this.legs + " legs and " + this.arms + " arms");
}

function Schnauzer(name) {
  Dog.call(this);
  this.name = name;
}

Schnauzer.prototype.describe = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is a Schnauzer with a shaggy beard");
  Dog.prototype.describe(this);
}

var my_dog = new Schnauzer("Rupert");
my_dog.describe();
```

My expectation here is that this would output:

```
Rupert is a Schnauzer with a shaggy beard
Has 4 legs and 0 arms
```

however this is what i actually get:

```
Rupert is a Schnauzer with a shaggy beard
Has undefined legs and undefined arms
```

Comment: Do you need to create a `new Dog` in `Schnauzer`? Shouldn't you be using `class` for this?

Comment: You are not actually inheriting `Schnauzer` from `Dog`. You need to set `Schnauzer.prototype = Object.create(Dog.prototype)` and add the constructor property back: `Schnauzer.prototype.constructor = Schnauzer`: [MDN: Inheritance in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
Dog.prototype.describe(this);
```

you're calling the `describe` method with a calling context (a `this` value) of `Dog.prototype`, and passing the dog instance as the first argument. But `describe` doesn't accept any arguments, and it tries to take properties from `this`.

Do `Dog.prototype.describe.call(this);` instead, to call the method with a `this` value of the dog instance:

```js
function Dog() {
  this.legs = 4;
  this.arms = 0;
}

Dog.prototype.describe = function() {
  console.log("Has " + this.legs + " legs and " + this.arms + " arms");
}

function Schnauzer(name) {
  Dog.call(this);
  this.name = name;
}

Schnauzer.prototype.describe = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is a Schnauzer with a shaggy beard");
  Dog.prototype.describe.call(this);
}

var my_dog = new Schnauzer("Rupert");
my_dog.describe();
```

Still, this is kind of ugly, since you have to use `.call` just to get to a method that, in a normal situation, would be higher up on the prototype chain of the current object. If possible, you might consider re-naming your `Schnauzer.prototype.describe` method, so it doesn't overshadow the `Dog.prototype` method:

```js
function Dog() {
  this.legs = 4;
  this.arms = 0;
}

Dog.prototype.describe = function() {
  console.log("Has " + this.legs + " legs and " + this.arms + " arms");
}

function Schnauzer(name) {
  Dog.call(this);
  this.name = name;
}
Schnauzer.prototype = Object.create(Dog.prototype);

Schnauzer.prototype.describeSchnauzer = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is a Schnauzer with a shaggy beard");
  this.describe();
}

var my_dog = new Schnauzer("Rupert");
my_dog.describeSchnauzer();
```

Or use `class` syntax and `super`:

```js
class Dog {
  legs = 4;
  arms = 0;
  describe() {
    console.log("Has " + this.legs + " legs and " + this.arms + " arms");
  }
}

class Schnauzer extends Dog {
  constructor(name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
  }
  describe() {
    console.log(this.name + " is a Schnauzer with a shaggy beard");
    super.describe();
  }
}

var my_dog = new Schnauzer("Rupert");
my_dog.describe();
```

Comment: The third option you have here is probably the most applicable.  I know class syntax is fairly new in javascript, is this widely supported?

Comment: Ordinary class syntax is ES2015, which the vast majority of browsers support, but not IE11. But to make code in modern syntax compatible with IE11, the answer is always to [use Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your syntax to ES5 automatically - this keeps your source code readable, in the latest and greatest version of the language, while allowing obsolete browsers to understand your production code.